# Problem involving conditional probability

Tags: probability

I am working on a problem that reads as follows:

*A new test has been developed to determine whether a given student is
overstressed. This test is 95% accurate if the student is not overstressed, but only 85%
accurate if the student is in fact overstressed.  It is known that 99.5% of all students
are overstressed. Given that a particular student tests negative for stress, what is the
probability that the test results are correct, and that this student is not overstressed?*

I understand that the answer I'm looking for is of the form $$P((A \cap S^c)|\text{tested negative for stress}),$$ where $A$ is the event that the test is accurate and $S$ is the event that the student is overstressed.

Furthermore, the remaining probabilities from the question are (I believe) $P(A|S)=0.85$ and $P(A|S^c)=0.95$. Assuming that these are correct, how would I use them to express the second half of the conditional probability above  (tested negative for stress)?

My first thought was that the test could be either accurate or inaccurate, which led me to $P((A\cap S^c)\cup(A^c\cap S))$.

Comment: You want $P(S^c|Neg)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem).

Denote $N$ as an event of negative test for student. 
So, we are given that the event $N$ occured. We want to find $P(A\vert N)$.

We have

$$P(S^c\vert N) = \dfrac{P(N\vert S^c)P(S^c)}{p(N)}$$

For $P(N)$ we have 
$$P(N) = P(N\vert S)P(S)+P(N\vert S^c)P(S^c).$$
And this quantity is computable from your statement.

$$P(S^c\vert N) = \dfrac{P(N\vert S^c)P(S^c)}{P(N\vert S)P(S)+P(N\vert S^c)P(S^c)}$$

Comment: Does this take into account the accuracy of the test results? It appears to read as "the probability that a student is not overstressed, given a negative test result", whereas I interpreted the question as asking for the probability that "the test is accurate *and* the student is not overstressed, given a negative test result".

Comment: Your statement tells "what is the probability that the test results are correct, and that this student is (not) overstressed". So, your student should be overstressed or not?

Comment: My mistake, it should be "not overstressed".

Comment: Nevermind, I now understand where I was confused. Thanks for your help!